# retrieving data from xml column sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a table with an xml type column (column name is Before)
here is a sample of the data

```
<row ID="47" By="Test User" Date="2006-07-26T00:00:00" Status="Closed" 
     Closed_Date="2012-06-22T11:14:35.237" Closed_By="MrBig" />
```

When I use this query to retrive the data, i get Nulls instead of the ID Numbers

```
SELECT    before.value('ID[1]', 'int') ItemId
FROM dbo.Audit
CROSS APPLY Before.nodes('.') N(C)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's an attribute, so you have to prefix it with `@`, like `@ID`.  An attribute must always be prefixed with a node, so the XPath query becomes `/row/@ID`.  For example:

```
SELECT  Before.value('(/row/@ID)[1]', 'int') ItemId
FROM    Audit
```

As far as I can see, there's no need for a `cross apply` here.

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af1b6/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to this:

```
SELECT before.value('@ID[1]', 'int') ItemId
FROM @Audit
CROSS APPLY Before.nodes('/row') N(C)
```

Use `.nodes('/row')` to select the `<row>` node - and use `@ID` to select the XML attribute.

However, using this, you'll get an error:

> Msg 2390, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   XQuery [@Audit.before.value()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported

Since you only have a single `<row>` element in your XML (that's correct, right?), you can use this instead:

```
SELECT 
    before.value('(row/@ID)[1]', 'int') ItemId
FROM dbo.Audit
```

Comment: You Sir Marc_S are my hero.   Sometimes, it takes another pair of eyes.   Especially when coding XML qeries at 3am PST.